# Массивы в языке C++

Tags: c++

Вот код почему он так работает:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[2] = {1,2};
    int arr2[2] = {545,321};
    cout << arr2[arr[-1]]; 
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод 545, почему вывело 545, а не мусор? А при 0 то выводит 321

Comment: ну то, что "при 0 то выводит 321", это как раз понятно

Comment: Доступ по индексу вне диапазона = UB. Может произойти что угодно, рассуждать о результате нет смысла.

Comment: Вывод будет зависеть от компилятора и ОС.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что `545` - это "не мусор"? Как вы "мусор" от "не мусора" отличаете?

Comment: Просто в памяти, куда попали при `arr[-1]` находится значение 0. Поэтому попадаем в `arr2[0]`

Comment: Массивы в C++ это хотя бы `std::array`.

Comment: @PinkTux это уже классовый тип

Comment: а по моему вы почти повторяете мой  вчерашный вопрос - прочитайте там ответы

Comment: Спасибо Croessmah и всем остальным!